# Can't set default selected radio button's option using ng-repeat in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my code:

```
    <label ng-repeat="option in product.DeliveryOptions" class="radio-inline product__filtr__form__label__input">
  <input type="radio" ng-model="product.SelectedDeliveryOption" ng-change="changeDeliveryType(product)" name="inlineRadioOptions{{product.ID}}"
class="product__filtr__form__radio" value="{{option.Method}}">{{option.Description}}
</label>
```

This is nested `ng-repeat` block. Parent block is `product in products`. As you can see each product has `SelectedDeliveryOption`. For example I have two radio buttons. Values(`option.Method`) - `"bronze"` for the first and `"silver"` for the second.  This value (`ng-model="product.SelectedDeliveryOption"`) is `"silver"`. But radio button isn't selected by default. I've tryed: `ng-checked = "option.Method == product.SelectedDeliveryOption"`, but doesn't work for me.

```
 $scope.initProductsTable = function (products) {
            $scope.products = products;    }
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Where is the javascript Code ?

Comment: please provide the js code as snippet

Comment: Just initialization of products $scope.initProducts = function(products){$scope.products = products}; and <div ng-init="initProducts(products)"></div>

Comment: how `$scope.products = products` looks like?

Comment: Edited my question. As I know, usual ng-init

Comment: please provide the entire js code so I can use your code as example

Comment: Alvaro, I'm using back-end logic for initialization. But as I see all is correct and should work like in your answer. This is a shot of values.http://prntscr.com/c5pz9c  And that is all.

Comment: To be clear, default value is selected, but radio button isn't marked as selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure if the `value` object `option.Method` in:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="product.SelectedDeliveryOption" ng-change="changeDeliveryType(product)" name="inlineRadioOptions{{product.ID}}"
class="product__filtr__form__radio" value="{{option.Method}}">
```

has the format:

```
option.Method = {"id": "12345",
            "value": "teste"}
```

and use `ng-value` directive;

like the example bellow:

When using `radio button` you have to make equal the `model` value and the `value` from the `radio button`:

check the snippet bellow:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('includeExample', ['ngAnimate'])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$q',
      function($scope, $q) {
       $scope.color = {
        name: 'blue'
      };
      $scope.specialValue = {
        "id": "12345",
        "value": "green"
      };        


      }
    ]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-animate.js"></script>

<body ng-app="includeExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <form novalidate class="simple-form">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="red">
    Red
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" ng-value="specialValue">
    Green
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="blue">
    Blue
  </label><br/>
  <tt>color = {{color.name | json}}</tt><br/>
  </form> 

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Alvaro, I've found a mistake. Thank you very much for help. The name of radio buttons was the same. Really, don't know how I missed it. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Np, I'm happy if I helped :)